# How do you say that you obtain n of A, B, and C?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say "You can get 2~4 each of necklace, ring, and bracelet from the box," in case that the person who opens the box obtains 2~4 necklaces, 2~4 rings, and 2~4 bracelets? Or, is there a more natural way of saying this?

Answer (score 1):

First, use an en dash rather than a tilde to represent a range. Second, use the plural rather than the singular to refer to multiple items.

So:

> You can get 2–4 each of necklaces, rings, and bracelets from the box.

I believe most people would interpret it the same way if you left out **each of** but it's possible some might not.

Perhaps slightly less awkward phrasings:

> From among necklaces, rings, and bracelets, you can get 2–4 of each from the box.
>
> You can get, respectively, 2–4 necklaces, rings, and bracelets from the box.

Answer (score 0):

More natural is a coveral term. In this case "You can take four items of each type of jewelery from the box."
You have to be careful with "each". If addressing more than one person this can mean each (person) if placed before the verb and otherwise be confusing if not explicitely tied to the object.